# What does (byte*)variable_name mean in C++?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

Gentlemen, 
  I am a novice C++ programmer, When I was trying to learn how to use EEPROM with Arduino, I came across this statement

> i2c_eeprom_write_page(0x57, 0, (byte *)somedata, sizeof(somedata));

where I need to know what does (byte*) somedata mean?, please let me know if someone know the answer

Regards,

Mr.B

Comment: external EEPROM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "Interpret this pointer as a pointer to byte data".  It's called "Casting" and allows you to fool the compiler into thinking that one type of data is another.

For example, your function expects a `byte *` (a pointer to byte data), and if you have `char *` as your variable you can change it on the fly to `byte *` by casting it like that.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Majenko Can you please refer me some material or website for me to learn more about this topic, It would be helpful . Thanks for the reply

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm

Comment: Thanks Mr.Majenko